# Dropdown in angular mat-table

Tags: angular

Here I'm using select in mat-table. The issue was when I select a option in dropdown all the other rows select affected. How can I solve this issue?

Here is my code-
html-

```
       <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="slno">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name of the customer</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
                        <span class="mx-md-2"> {{element.CustomerName}}</span>

                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="product" mat-sort-header>
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center">Item name</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: center">
                        <select class="form-control buttondrop" [(ngModel)]="selectedDataList"
                         style="width:130px" (change)="changed(element.CustomerId)">
                            <option disabled value="undefined" >--Select--</option>
                            <option selected [ngValue]="item" 
                                *ngFor="let item of element.followUpLists">
                                {{item.ProductName}}
                            </option>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="name" mat-sort-header>
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center">Mac id</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: center;width:120px">
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==false">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].MacId }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId==element.CustomerId">
                            {{List.MacId }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId!=element.CustomerId">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].MacId }}
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="weight" mat-sort-header>
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AMC start date</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: center">
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==false">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].AMCStartDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId==element.CustomerId">
                            {{List.AMCStartDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId!=element.CustomerId">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].AMCStartDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>AMC end date</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: center">

                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==false">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].AMCEndDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId==element.CustomerId">
                            {{List.AMCEndDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="SelectionChanged==true && UniqueId!=element.CustomerId">
                            {{element.followUpLists[0].AMCEndDate | date: 'mediumDate' }}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns2"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns2;"></tr>
                <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                    <td class="mat-cell text-center" colspan="6">No data found </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

ts-

SelectionChanged:boolean=false;

changed(id) {

```
  console.log("id",id);
  this.UniqueId=id;
  this.List=this.selectedDataList;
  console.log("list",this.List);
  this.SelectionChanged=true;
```

}

Screenshots-

1.[Initially displayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYTaK.png)

2.[After selecting a option, it look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTqvA.png)

Comment: It seems that you are binding the same value for every row on select with ngModel...  try omitting assigning value to test if this is a problem  [(ngModel)]="selectedDataList"

Comment: I imagine you want to do `<select [(ngModel)]="element.CustomerId"...>` (and remove the `(change)` event

Answer (score 0):

check out this,maybe it can help you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wwnxyjrnr8?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
selectedCar: FormControl;
selectedOwner: FormControl;
cars: any[];
owners: any[];
services: any[];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private carService: 
CarService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.refresh();

    this.selectedCar = this.fb.control(null);
    this.selectedOwner = this.fb.control(null);

    this.selectedCar.valueChanges.subscribe(selectedCarId => {
        this.carService.getOwnersFromCar(selectedCarId).subscribe(owners => {
            this.owners = owners;
        });
    });

    this.selectedOwner.valueChanges.subscribe(selectedOwnerId => {
        this.carService.getServiceHistory(this.selectedCar.value).subscribe(history => {
            this.services = history;
            if (history && history.length > 0) {
                history.flatMap(service => {
                    return this.services = service.details;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

refresh() {
    this.carService.getAllCars().subscribe(cars => {
        this.cars = cars;
    });
}
delete(serviceId: number) {
    this.carService.deleteServiceRecord(serviceId).subscribe(() 
=> {
        this.services = this.services?.filter(service => service.id !== serviceId);
    });
}

edit(serviceId: number, updatedServiceRecord: any) {
    this.carService.editServiceRecord(serviceId, 
updatedServiceRecord).subscribe(() => {
        // Find the service record in the this.services array
        const serviceIndex = this.services.findIndex(service => 
service.id === serviceId);
        if (serviceIndex !== -1) {
            // Updating the service record in the array
            this.services[serviceIndex] = { 
 ...this.services[serviceIndex], ...updatedServiceRecord };
        }
    });
}
```

}